# Xcode storyboard doesn't fit iPhone screen

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

I have problem with Xcode storyboard editor, when I add something what is bigger than half(?) scrren that is too big (look on screen)[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlBgb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your `textField` and add this constraints as shown into below image.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I just wish this question hadn't been asked thousands of times :( It's getting like the NSDate - NSString question.

Comment: What do you use to create the gif?

Comment: Thank you, u saved my developing life.